# Customized Camera Toolbar on iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uitoolbar

I've created a camera application for iPhone and now I sit and polish the last of it. My application is a collage application where the user can take multiple pictures in a row.

As it is today I have a customized camera view that contains one UIButton for taking the pictures and one UIButton for getting back to the main view.

The problem is that my application is design for landscape mode and the camera control can only show in portrait mode. This makes the design of the GUI a little bit tricky and I now want to move away from having the buttons in the view to having the placed in a toolbar. When you initialize the camera you can set a bunch of different parameters and one of them is **UIImagePickerController.toolbarHidden**. If I set the value to **NO** it will show an empty toolbar and my question here is, **how do I add items to this toolbar?**

I've tried different solutions without any luck.

Thanks,
drisse

Answer (score 1):

Does the standard UIViewController method -setToolBarItems:animated: method not work?

Comment: Hi,
No it doesn't. I've tried to call that method both from the UIViewController that owns the camera and I've also tried to call that method from inside my own subclass of UIImagePickerController but nothing works. It's very strange that I can decide to hide or show the toolbar but I can't add any items to it!?

Comment: Have you tried, in your subclass of UIImagePickerController, overriding the -toolbar property to return a different toolbar that you create yourself? It's possible that the standard UIImagePickerController is returning a broken/nil toolbar.

Comment: That might be a solution, but how do I override a property (You'll have to forgive me I'm a newbie in Objective-C)?

Comment: The strange thing is that I can change the color of the toolbar like this: UIToolbar *tb = self.toolbar;
tb.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Comment: @drisse, I cannot change the toolbar color by : imagePicker.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; are you sure you can change it ?